# DJango query omtimization for foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

```
class MainCategory(models.Model):
    main_category_id = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    image = models.URLField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'lookup_main_category'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class SubCategory(models.Model):
    sub_category_id = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    main_category = models.ForeignKey(MainCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.URLField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'lookup_sub_category'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I have the above 2 models in my DJango REST framework project and I need an API output as below. What will be the optimum query without having typical for loop to get distinct main categories and then loop through it in the sub_category table?

```
[
  {
    "main_category_id": "10",
    "main_category_name": "main_name1",
    "image": "http://example/com1",
    "sub_categories": [
      {
        "sub_category_id": "20",
        "sub_category_name": "sub_name1",
        "image": "http://example/com1"
      },
      {
        "sub_category_id": "21",
        "sub_category_name": "sub_name2",
        "image": "http://example/com"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "main_category_id": "11",
    "main_category_name": "main_name2",
    "image": "http://example/com2",
    "sub_categories": [
      {
        "sub_category_id": "22",
        "sub_category_name": "sub_name2",
        "image": "http://example/com2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you would take advantage of `prefetch_related`, which performs two SQL queries and does an in-memory JOIN.

```py
queryset = MainCategory.objects.prefetch_related('subcategory_set')
```

Then you iterate over this queryset serializing each object with it's subcategories without hitting the DB.

More info. on official docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

Comment: prefetch_related is to fetch the parent table data from the child table. Here the requirement is the other way.

Answer (score 0):

Finally this is how I managed to get the expected result.

Trick was to use the _set.all()

Official docs are [here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/)

```
categories_result = []
main_categories = MainCategory.objects.all()
for main_category in main_categories:
    main_cat_data = MainCategorySerializer(main_category, many=False)
    sub_categories = main_category.subcategory_set.all()
    sub_categories_data = SubCategorySerializer(sub_categories, many=True)
    result_info = {'main_category': main_cat_data.data, 'sub_categories': sub_categories_data.data}
    categories_result.append(result_info)
```